# ExtJS 7.x Modern, How to Drag and Drop from Grid to Grid Tree?

Tags: extjs-grid, extjs7

I'm looking for an example of how to implement a row drag and drop from a grid to a grid tree. This would be using the Modern toolkit.

It works when I drag and drop from one grid to another but when I drag over a tree grid no drop target becomes active. How to I get the tree grid's drop zone to "accept" a row[s] dragged from a grid?